# How to solve a system of $4$ equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, systems-of-equations

I would like to solve the following system of equations in $ \mathbb{C} $ :
$$ \begin{cases} x+2y+3z+4t+3xy-2zt = 1 \\ 4x+y+2z+3t+2xy-4zt = 3 \\ 3x+4y+z+2t-xy+zt = -1 \\ 2x+3y+4z+t+4xy+2zt = 2 \end{cases} $$
I'm not able to solve it unfortunatly.
The idea is to transform this system in another system of the form :
$$ \begin{cases} a_{11}(x+y)+a_{12}(z+t)+a_{13} \ xy+a_{14} \ zt = b_{1} \\ a_{21}(x+y)+a_{22}(z+t)+a_{23} \ xy+a_{24}\ zt = b_{2} \\ 
a_{31}(x+y)+a_{32}(z+t)+a_{33} \ xy+a_{34} \ zt = b_{1} \\ a_{41}(x+y)+a_{42}(z+t)+a_{43} \ xy+a_{44} \ zt = b_{4} \end{cases} $$
such that : $ A = (a_{ij})_{1 \leq i,j \leq 4} $ is an invertible matrix, which is easy to solve in this case, right ? But, i don't know how to do it.
Could you help me please ?

Thank you.

Comment: The equation system is not linear, so this approach unfortunately does not work.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not really sure that the approach doesn't work because the equation system is not linear. I think, there is another reason why this approach doesn't work, no ? Not because the equation system is not linear. :-)

Comment: You can find linear combinations of the given equations in which the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ are equal and also the coefficients of $z$ and $t$ are equal. For example, add all the equations together and see what you get. Each such linear combination could be an equation of your transformed system. Whether you can find four linearly independent equations like that is a question I have not worked out.

Comment: @DavidK : I tried this idea that you talk about, but i don't get the solution yet. I think this is possible, because we have a system with $4$ equations and $ 6 $ vaiables, so the columns of the matrix corresponding to this system are not linearly independent. Can you write the answer, if we follow your idea ? Thank you.

Comment: On second thought I think linear combinations of the given equations can give you only two independent equations of the form you're looking for. (See the remark about the rank of the matrix of $x,y,z,t$ coefficients in one of the answers.) Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using resultants or Buchberger's algorithm we obtain first two linear equations, which we can substitute:
$$
x= \frac{132t^2 + 167t - 6}{8(31t - 1)},\; y= \frac{-144t^2 -125t -2 }{8(31t - 1)}
$$
Then we immediately obtain
$$
z=\frac{116t + 11}{4(31t - 1)}.
$$
This yields, for the remaining equation, then
$$
19008t^4 + 37076t^3 + 18775t^2 - 2844t + 68=0.
$$
This has $4$ solutions. $2$ of them are real.

Comment: Thank you very much @Dietrich Burde. :-) But i dont really know how to use resultants to obtain the two linear equations that you talk about. Can you show me how to do it please ? Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do the substitution you want since the $4\times 4$ matrix with the coefficients of $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ has rank $4$. What you can do is reduce to an equivalent system in $xy$ and $zt$, as follows:

HINT:

Write  $xy = p$, $zt = q$, and think of them as parameters. Solve the linear system in $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ and get 
$$x = 1/40 (2 p + 23 q + 25) \\y = 1/40 (22 p - 47 q - 35) \\ z = 1/40 (-58 p - 7 q + 35) \\ t = 1/40 (2 p + 43 q - 5)$$

So we get 
$$p  = 1/1600(2p+23 q +25)(22 p - 47 q -35)\\
q = 1/1600(- 58 p - 7 q + 35)(2 p + 43 q -5)$$
hence an equivalent system of equations in $p$, $q$. That can be solved in principle.